# Unable to click on not currently visible element in dropdown menu

Tags: selenium, c#

In dropdown list is element "Set time" but this element is not currently visible.
[image]

I was trying set `driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();` and also window size to 1920, 1080.

```
Assert.IsTrue(driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Set time")).Displayed);
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Set time")).Click();
Thread.Sleep(2000);
driver.FindElement(By.Id("retM")).Clear();
driver.FindElement(By.Id("retM")).SendKeys("1");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnOK_CD")).Click();
```

I'm unable to click on element by:

```
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Set time")).Click();
```

and in the next step of code:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("retM")).Clear();
```

I got exception Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated.

I was trying to select element by XPath, by CSS, by Id...with same result.

Please, can you help me how to click on not currently visible element in dropdown menu ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

That the whole point of Selenium. If user cannot do it (like when element is hidden), Selenium (by design) does not allow to do that.

Answer (score 0):

After opening the drop down menu, try to scroll down till the link you want to click is visible and then click it.

Try to scroll with something like,

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.id("element-id"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.MoveToElement(element);
actions.Perform();
```

**OR**

```
driver.FindElementByClassName("body").SendKeys(Keys.PageDown);
```

followed by your code to click on the link.